# Any working multilingual option for Sharepoint Online site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, multilingual, mui

While setting up a small SharePoint site, I need to get multilinguarity: The site language is Swedish, but one subsite should be translated to Finnish for some users (those have no access to other subsites).

We decided that the tables and content in this subsite will have Finnish names/column names, therefore no need for content and page/list title translation - It is mainly the file option and navigation expressions (marked in the picture) that needs to be somehow translated.

Through research I thought that MUI might be the thing, but after setting up alternate languages, changing user and browser language, even given it some days to update, still no change whatsoever.

Is the MUI meant to do this kind of translation, or would any other (free) option fit us better?

[image]